# How do Sea Dragon style launches affect the Nozzle?

Tags: launch-sequence, sea-launch, sea-dragon

The [Sea Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Dragon_(rocket)) was a concept rocket to be towed empty to its marine launch-site, where it would be filled and turned upright through the weight of its propellant and some ballast. "Then it launches."

I don't understand what launching under water does to a nozzle and what steps are necessary to avoid failure.

How does the launch-procedure for a nozzle submerged in water look like? Does it require special nozzles? Are there restrictions on the engine? (such as regenerative cooling freezing the water during startup?) Is turbine-spinup via propellant flow even possible?

---

Background on why/what I'm asking:
I found no detail on whether the nozzle would get in touch with water, the closest being Wikipedia stating

> The ballast tanks, which also served as a cap and protection for the first-stage engine bell, [...]

Assuming the cap is water-tight, does that imply the nozzle needs to be able to withstand outside pressure? The alternative would be to pressurize the bell.

How would such a cap be safely removed during startup? (without water sloshing in, pressure rising in the bell, bell-rim buckling, ...) It's basically an overexpanded nozzle at that depth.

Then again, is it maybe possible to just put a nozzle in water and start a pressure-fed engine? I've been pondering this and can't find a hard reason why it would be impossible. When turning on the engine, hot gases drive out the water and that's it.

An article on the Sea Horse test-vehicle simply states it was [lowered into water, without problems for startup](https://web.archive.org/web/20160728041625/http://www.astronautix.com/s/seahorse.html). A couple of years back there was Ripple Aerospace trying to achieve a spike-nozzle Sea Dragon like rocket. Best I could find on them is [a thread where one of the co-founders chipped in](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=5l3nvgfs2slujljldh93qjlq4m&topic=45364.0;all). A [post there mentions that the Seabee](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=5l3nvgfs2slujljldh93qjlq4m&topic=45364.msg1806675#msg1806675) got water into it's combustion chamber and *therefore* started smoothly, which I find hard to believe.

Comment: I count 7 questions in this post. It would seem to require a book to answer all those questions. Fortunately one has been written and you can read it here http://neverworld.net/truax/

Comment: Just for entertainment https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQDe0rCsd0Q